# Пропуск бит в структуре

Tags: visual-c++, c++, visual-studio

Есть структура, примерно следующего содержания:

```
struct tst{
    unsigned short a:9;
    unsigned short b:9;
    unsigned short c:9;
    unsigned short d:9;
    unsigned short e:9;
    unsigned short f:9;
    unsigned short g:9;
    unsigned short h:9;
    unsigned short i:9;
    unsigned short j:9;
    unsigned short k:9;
    unsigned short l:9;
    unsigned short m:9;
    unsigned short n:9;
    unsigned short z:2;
};
```

Проблема в том, что ее размер намного превышает размер по сумме бит. С int та же фигня, но в меньших масштабах. Как мне получить структуру без потери бит? Я копирую в нее структуру приходящую по сети пропущенные биты ломают ее.
Сейчас пробую под винду, но понадобится еще и под линукс.

Comment:  #pragma pack( push, 2 )
 struct tst{
     unsigned short a:9;
     unsigned short b:9;
     unsigned short c:9;
     unsigned short d:9;
     unsigned short e:9;
     unsigned short f:9;
     unsigned short g:9;
     unsigned short h:9;
     unsigned short i:9;
     unsigned short j:9;
     unsigned short k:9;
     unsigned short l:9;
     unsigned short m:9;
     unsigned short n:9;
     unsigned short z:2;
 };
 #pragma pack(pop)

Comment: Пробовал, не помогает. Эта штука как мне кажется немного для других целей.

Comment: А, точно! В short не входит ровное число полей, вот и получаются дыры. Нужно подобрать такую базу, чтобы она вмещала кратное число полей, тогда пропусков не будет.

Comment: Да. И это печально. Даже в int не влазит, и в int64. Похоже остается написать умный код, который скопирует данные в мою структуру учитывая пропуски бит.

Comment: Для разминки мозгов:

 template< int Offset, int Size, typename Type, typename Ancestor >
 struct BitField : public Ancestor{
  operator Type( void )const{
   Type No, Rem;
   //
   No = Offset / RTL_BITS_OF( Type );
   Rem = Offset % RTL_BITS_OF( Type );
   if( Rem + Size >= RTL_BITS_OF( Type ) ){
    throw;
   }
   return ((const Type*)this)[No] >> Rem;
  }
 };
использовать можно так:

 struct X{ char fields[16]; } x;
 char a, b;
 a = static_cast< BitField< 0, 9, char, X >& >( x );
 b = static_cast< BitField< 9, 9, char, X >& >( x );
 ...

Comment: @mikelsv, gcc (g++) укладывают эту структуру в 28 байт (unsigned short), 20 байт (uint32_t) и **16 байт !!!** (uint64_t).

Для передаче по сети можно сделать htonll()/ntohll() (аналогичные htonl()/ntohl()).


Но, @Котик\_хочет\_кушать прав, в гетерогенной среде эта штука может и не работать.

--

А вообще попобробней опишите задачу. Вы обмениваетесь такой структурой со своими программами или это откуда-то получаемые 128 бит, которые структурированы подобным образом (сначала 14 раз по 9 бит, а потом еще 2 бита)?

Answer (score 6):

- **Никогда** не используйте `bitfield` для подобных вещей.

> `-` `[C99, 6.7.2.1]`
>
> An implementation may allocate any addressable storage unit large enough to hold a bit- field. If enough space remains, a bit-field that immediately follows another bit-field in a structure shall be packed into adjacent bits of the same unit. If insufficient space remains, whether a bit-field that does not fit is put into the next unit or overlaps adjacent units is implementation-defined. The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to low-order or low-order to high-order) **is implementation-defined.** The alignment of the addressable storage unit **is unspecified.**
>
> `-` `[C++03, 9.6]`
>
> Allocation of bit-fields within a class object **is implementation-defined.** Alignment of bit-fields **is implementation-defined.** Bit-fields are packed into some addressable allocation unit.

- Используйте побитовые операции над полученным потоком данных или же [`std::bitset`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/bitset/bitset/) в случае `C++`.

Comment: Сначала думал - это не ответ на вопрос. Но если смотреть не на вопрос, а на задачу, то да - структурные биты для нее не подходят. (реабилитировал)

Answer (score 2):

Собственно, отвечаю в продолжение идеи о классе `BitField` из комментария. Только с апгрейдом его до рекурсии в `compile-time`:

```
#ifndef RTL_BITS_OF
    #define RTL_BITS_OF( type ) ( 8 * sizeof( type ) )
#endif

template< int Offset, int Size, typename Type, typename Anc, bool Ok >
struct CTBitFieldChecked;
//
template< int Offset, int Size, typename Type, typename Anc >
struct CTBitFieldChecked< Offset, Size, Type, Anc, true > : public Anc{
    //
    static const Type Bits  = Type( RTL_BITS_OF( Type ) );
    static const Type No    = Type( Offset / Bits );
    static const Type Rem   = Type( Offset % Bits );
    static const Type MGet  = Type( ( Type( 1 ) << Size ) - 1 );
    static const Type MBSet = Type( 1 ) << Rem;
    static const Type MSet  = ( MBSet - 1 ) | ~( ( MBSet << Size ) - 1 );
    static const Type MISet = ~MSet;
    //
    operator Type( void )const{
        const Type&N    = ((const Type*)static_cast< const Anc* >( this ))[No];
        //
        return( N >> Rem ) & MGet;
    }
    CTBitFieldChecked&operator=( const Type Value ){
        Type&N  = ((Type*)static_cast< Anc* >( this ))[No];
        //
        return( N = ( N & MSet ) | ( ( Value << Rem ) & MISet ) ), *this;
    }
};
//
template< int Offset, int Size, typename Type, typename Anc >
struct CTBitFieldChecked< Offset, Size, Type, Anc, false > : public Anc{
    //
    static const Type Bits      = Type( RTL_BITS_OF( Type ) );
    static const Type No        = Type( Offset / Bits );
    static const Type Rem       = Type( Offset % Bits );
    static const Type LoSize    = Type( Size / 2 );
    static const Type HiSize    = Type( Size - LoSize );
    static const Type HiOffset  = Type( Offset + LoSize );
    static const Type RemHi     = HiOffset % Bits;
    //
    typedef CTBitFieldChecked<
        Offset, LoSize, Type, Anc, ( Rem + LoSize ) <= Bits
    >Lo;
    typedef CTBitFieldChecked<
        HiOffset, HiSize, Type, Anc, ( RemHi + HiSize ) <= Bits
    >Hi;
    //
    operator Type( void )const{
        Type vLo    = *static_cast< const Lo* >( static_cast< const Anc* >( this ) );
        Type vHi    = *static_cast< const Hi* >( static_cast< const Anc* >( this ) );
        return vLo | ( vHi << LoSize );
    }
    CTBitFieldChecked&operator=( const Type Value ){
        *static_cast< Lo* >( static_cast< Anc* >( this ) )  = Value;
        *static_cast< Hi* >( static_cast< Anc* >( this ) )  = Value >> LoSize;
        return*this;
    }
};
//
template< int Offset, int Size, typename Type, typename Anc >
struct CTBitField : public Anc{
    //
    static const Type Bits  = Type( RTL_BITS_OF( Type ) );
    static const Type No    = Type( Offset / Bits );
    static const Type Rem   = Type( Offset % Bits );
    //
    typedef CTBitFieldChecked<
        Offset, Size, Type, Anc, ( Rem + Size ) <= Bits
    >Checked;
    //
    operator Type( void )const{
        return*static_cast< const Checked* >( static_cast< const Anc* >( this ) );
    }
    CTBitField&operator=( const Type Value ){
        *static_cast< Checked* >( static_cast< Anc* >( this ) ) = Value;
        return*this;
    }
};
```

Идея этого класса заключается в том, что если поле не вмещается в `Type`, то оно делится пополам до тех пор, пока не вместится ( или не "выродится" в `Size=1` или `Size=0` [при нуле - не скомпилируется] ). Вместится оно в том случае, если `RTL_BITS_OF( Type ) >= Size`. Следует учитывать так же, что у знаковых типов последний бит не используется. Но в таком случае (если не хватит бит) класс просто не скомпилируется.

А вообще, запретить `signed` довольно просто:

> template< int Offset, int Size, typename Type, typename Anc >
> struct CTBitFieldChecked< Offset, Size, **unsigned** Type, Anc, ... > : public Anc{
>  ...
> };

Для разнообразия, здесь можно сделать проверку от дурака: на выход `Offset + Size` за пределы `Anc` и на выход `Size` за пределы `Type`.

Пример использования:

```
struct tst{
    char raw[16];
};
//
typedef CTBitField< 0, 9, unsigned short, tst >A;
typedef CTBitField< 9, 9, unsigned short, tst >B;
typedef CTBitField< 18, 9, unsigned short, tst >C;
typedef CTBitField< 27, 9, unsigned short, tst >D;
typedef CTBitField< 36, 9, unsigned short, tst >E;
typedef CTBitField< 45, 9, unsigned short, tst >F;
typedef CTBitField< 54, 9, unsigned short, tst >G;
typedef CTBitField< 63, 9, unsigned short, tst >H;
typedef CTBitField< 72, 9, unsigned short, tst >I;
typedef CTBitField< 81, 9, unsigned short, tst >J;
typedef CTBitField< 90, 9, unsigned short, tst >K;
typedef CTBitField< 99, 9, unsigned short, tst >L;
typedef CTBitField< 108, 9, unsigned short, tst >M;
typedef CTBitField< 117, 9, unsigned short, tst >N;
typedef CTBitField< 126, 2, unsigned short, tst >Z;
//
tst s;
//
static_cast< A& >( s )  = 1;
static_cast< B& >( s )  = 2;
static_cast< C& >( s )  = 3;
static_cast< D& >( s )  = 4;
static_cast< E& >( s )  = 5;
static_cast< F& >( s )  = 6;
static_cast< G& >( s )  = 7;
static_cast< H& >( s )  = 8;
static_cast< I& >( s )  = 9;
static_cast< J& >( s )  = 10;
static_cast< K& >( s )  = 11;
static_cast< L& >( s )  = 12;
static_cast< M& >( s )  = 13;
static_cast< N& >( s )  = 14;
static_cast< Z& >( s )  = 3;
//
unsigned short  a   = static_cast< const A& >( s );
unsigned short  b   = static_cast< const B& >( s );
unsigned short  c   = static_cast< const C& >( s );
unsigned short  d   = static_cast< const D& >( s );
unsigned short  e   = static_cast< const E& >( s );
unsigned short  f   = static_cast< const F& >( s );
unsigned short  g   = static_cast< const G& >( s );
unsigned short  h   = static_cast< const H& >( s );
unsigned short  i   = static_cast< const I& >( s );
unsigned short  j   = static_cast< const J& >( s );
unsigned short  k   = static_cast< const K& >( s );
unsigned short  l   = static_cast< const L& >( s );
unsigned short  m   = static_cast< const M& >( s );
unsigned short  n   = static_cast< const N& >( s );
unsigned short  z   = static_cast< const Z& >( s );
```

По-моему, задачу такой шаблон решает оч. красиво :)

Comment: Красиво, не поспоришь, но слишком много кода и шаблонов.
Откопал старый вариант, решающий задачу просто и красиво:

unsigned int gu(unsigned char *buf, int pos, int len){
  unsigned int bits=0;
  int i;
  for(i=pos; i<pos+len; i++) bits=(bits<<1)+((buf[i/8]>>(7-i%8))&1u);
  return bits;
 }

Передаем буфер, позицию и длину в битах, получаем результат.
Но и этот вариант мне не нравится, я хочу передвинуть данные в структуре в соответствии с дырками, что позволит вообще не работать с битами. На мой взгляд это будет самый идеальный вариант.

Comment: Шаблона всего 2. А кода на самом деле почти нет, в `run-time` это все выродится в несколько команд маскирования, в отличие от Вашего побитового цикла. И делений у меня вообще нет, они самые прожорливые. Впрочем, делений и у Вас нет (они так же выродятся до сдвигов и маскировки), но цикл просто неконкурентноспособен.

Answer (score 2):

Офтоп, потому что так можно только в GCC

```
union new_type
{
    struct
    {
        unsigned short a:9;
        unsigned short b:9;
        unsigned short c:9;
        unsigned short d:9;
        unsigned short e:9;
        unsigned short f:9;
        unsigned short g:9;
        unsigned short h:9;
        unsigned short i:9;
        unsigned short j:9;
        unsigned short k:9;
        unsigned short l:9;
        unsigned short m:9;
        unsigned short n:9;
        unsigned short z:2;
    }__attribute__((packed)) bitfield;
    char data[16];
};

int main()
{
    new_type var = {0};
    printf("sizeof(tst): %d\n", (int)sizeof(var));
    var.data[1] = 15;
    printf("b: %d\n", var.bitfield.b);
    for(int i=0; i<128; i++) printf("%d", (int)(var.data[i/8]>>(i%8))&1);
    printf("\n");
}
```

вывод:

```
sizeof(tst): 16
b: 7
00000000111100000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Comment: вопрос был про vs